# #warning Handle the error here

Tags: xcode

I've got a bit of code from an open source Objective-C library which has around a dozen lines of code like this:

```
#warning Handle the error here.
```

which throws up warnings in Xcode. However, I like to get my warnings down to zero in Xcode before releasing a project.

How do I do this without editing the source of this third party library?

I'm using Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503).

==== UPDATE

More code:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryFromPlistData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryParsed = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
                                                                               options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                                format:nil
                                                                            error:&error];
    if (!dictionaryParsed)
    {
        if (error)
        {
#warning Handle the error here.
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return dictionaryParsed;
}
```

Comment: What are the warnings about?  Are they simply place holders?

Comment: are you using cocoapods?

Comment: @trojanfoe - see above for more code.

Comment: @ArtFeel no, I'm not using cocoapods.

Answer (score 1):

I would either:

1. Ignore the warnings.
2. Comment out the `#warning` statements.
3. Provide the needed error handling.

The code is incomplete, and if you do 3. (above) then you can contribute to this Open Source project and give something back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods, you can add it into your Podfile:
`pod 'SSZipArchive', :inhibit_warnings => true`

Or even disable warnings for all 3rd-party libraries by adding this line on top of your Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

More info in CocoaPods [documantation](http://docs.cocoapods.org/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang).
If you are not using CocoaPods, simply comment all this lines.